# What other programming languages run on PNaCl?

Tags: google-nativeclient

As I understand it, PNaCl is designed to support C and C++. Has anyone managed to get any other languages (that compile to native code) to run in PNaCl?

Answer (score 4):

Ruby, Lua, and a number of other languages have been ported to NaCl already. See the list of NaCl ports for full documentation. https://code.google.com/p/naclports/wiki/PortList

Comment: Are those Ruby and Lua interpreters written in C/C++?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen: Ok, thanks. I am only interested in languages that compile to native code.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of different approaches for targeting other languages to PNaCl. One is compiling the language interpreter with the PNaCl toolchain. Since most interpreters/VMs are written in C and C++, this turns out to be easy in practice. naclports already has Lua, Python and Ruby running in this manner.

A more direct approach is taken by [llgo](http://blog.awilkins.id.au/2012/12/go-in-browser-llgo-does-pnacl.html) - actually emitting PNaCl bitcode. There were also discussions about Mono (which does run on NaCl) on PNaCl - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/native-client-discuss/Km1FOVH6yn0

The real answer is - it's still early (PNaCl was released publicly last week!); this is a ripe field for disruption because the technology is new. If someone wants to port other languages, it would be very welcome.

Comment: any developments here?